# Unable to create a new core Solr 3.5. Error in default implementation of CREATE

Tags: solr, tomcat5.5

I am running Solr 3.5 and already have two cores set up by my senior. I need to add a new core. The Solr home is /runtime/local/solr/. This directory contains the Solr.xml. So I create a new directory here with my core's name and then run the following

```
 http://localhost:7658/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=core0&instanceDir=/runtime/local/solr/core0/
```

And Apache tomcat keeps returning a 400 error with the message

```
Error executing default implementation of CREATE
```

and the description says

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Error executing default implementation of CREATE).
```

What is going wrong here. The syntax seems to be correct from what I've searched on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each core requires its own configuration, so you do need to have the conf folder set-up but it does not need to be the same as the configuration for your first core

Comment: Yes. This is true. But in my case, except for schema.xml, the others remained the same. So I changed only the solr schema and then created the core.

Comment: I don't understand how this is an acceptable answer. We are just supposed to know how to create this unknown said required "configuration"?

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix. Not sure if it's the right approach. I created a directory for my core in the Solr Home folder and within it added a folder called conf. To this folder, I copied all the files which were there in the conf folder of the other core and after that ran the CREATE command. Booyah ! It worked.